# Postgres union of queries in loop

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with two columns. Let's call them
`array_column` and `text_column`

I'm trying to write a query to find out, for K ranging from 1 to 10, in how many rows does the value in `text_column` appear in the first K elements of `array_column`

I'm expecting results like:

```
k    |    count
________________
1    |    70
2    |    85
3    |    90
...
```

I did manage to get these results by simply repeating the query 10 times and uniting the results, which looks like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS k, count(*) FROM table WHERE array_column[1:1] @> ARRAY[text_column]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS k, count(*) FROM table WHERE array_column[1:2] @> ARRAY[text_column]
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS k, count(*) FROM table WHERE array_column[1:3] @> ARRAY[text_column]
...
```

But that doesn't looks like the correct way to do it. What if I wanted a very large range for K?

So my question is, is it possible to perform queries in a loop, and unite the results from each query? Or, if this is not the correct approach to the problem, how would you do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `generate_series` function to generate a table with the expected number of rows with the expected values and then join to it within the query, like so:

```
SELECT t.k AS k, count(*) 
FROM table 
--right join ensures that you will get a value of 0 if there are no records meeting the criteria
right join (select generate_series(1,10) as k) t 
 on array_column[1:t.k] @> ARRAY[text_column]
group by t.k
```

This is probably the closest thing to using a loop to go through the results without using something like PL/SQL to do an actual loop in a user-defined function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_positions()` which returns an array of all positions where the argument was found in the array, e.g.

```
select t.*, 
       array_positions(array_column, text_column)
from the_table t;
```

This returns a different result but is a lot more efficient as you don't need to increase the overall size of the result. To only consider the first ten array elements, just pass a slice to the function:

```
select t.*, 
       array_positions(array_column[1:10], text_column)
from the_table t;
```

To limit the result to only rows that actually contain the value you can use:

```
select t.*, 
       array_positions(array_column[1:10], text_column)
from the_table t
where text_column = any(array_column[1:10]);
```

To get your desired result, you could use unnest() to turn that into rows:

```
select k, count(*)
from the_table t, unnest(array_positions(array_column[1:10], text_column)) as k
where text_column = any(array_column[1:10])
group by k
order by k;
```